# Creating pure CSS smooth parallax in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, parallax

My website features a parallax effect using HTML and CSS. It works in Firefox as intended.. Working, fluid and smooth.

My dilemma is that when I test the feature in Chrome and IE the effect becomes choppy and is therefore very sore on the eyes.

I have had a look online and I can only find JQ and JS fixes. Is there any way to do this using CSS only? Because as far as I'm aware there is no place demonstrating how it can be done.

```
.slide1 {
    height: 40em;
    background: url(http://www.leejackson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/placeholder.png) center; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGxBKQ

Comment: There's no parallax effect happening in your CodePen. It's just normal scrolling.

Comment: Are you sure? Because it's visible for me. I will admit it's the first time I've used Codepen so I may have missed something obvious, although I think not.

Comment: In web design, a parallax effect is when you have two objects (usually two background planes/objects) that are moving at different speeds relative to one another when you scroll. In your CodePen, I only see the body scrolling, while the background is fixed. What you have is just smooth scrolling, not a parallax effect. See http://www.dangersoffracking.com/ for an example: the clouds are all moving on scroll, but some are moving faster than others; *that's* parallax.

Comment: I understand that. Maybe it's just a terminology issue or different way of doing something that produces the same effect but that website has the same problem I have. In IE that effect looks horrible, almost broken. Where as in Firefox it's smooth as a whistle.

Comment: Some of [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+can+I+fix+jerky+scrolling+in+IE%3F+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=how+can+I+fix+jerky+scrolling+in+IE%3F+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=serp.3...4483.8462.0.8508.23.19.0.0.0.0.151.1374.10j5.15.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..23.0.0.CodhQnNoZc0) might be useful to solving your scrolling issue.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks but those results did not help me.

Comment: Which one did you try? Did you get different results?

Comment: You may be using the wrong terminology. If you're looking for the name of the effect that you've created it is called a [collapsing header](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-collapsing-header-effect)

Answer (score -4):

You are on the right way, but the certain paralax effect is done with javascript..so use it.. css is ONLY for styling.. javascript is doing animations

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been playing long so I'm only trying things out primarily using CSS. Although it works and does what it is supposed to (in one browser) It's still not good enough for me so maybe I was just wrong in thinking this was usable. Thanks for your input and maybe in the near future I'll try again when I start learning JavaScript.

Comment: This is a borderline comment post. You should expand your answer to include more factual details.

Comment: Hey bro, I thing my answer helped him... so why are you giving me minus points? DONT CARE!! :)